# To reduce obesity, can I depend on elliptical trainer exercise at high resistance?

Tags: weight-loss, elliptical

I'm a man, 28 y.o., about 100 kg and 6 feet tall. I want to avoid weights if possible for a few months of initial training. I'm of the skinny fat types

Comment: To reduce obesity you should eat less AND move more.

Comment: Thanks, I'm seeking help on whether elliptical alone can be great for reducing fat, without weights

Comment: Being at a caloric deficit causes you to lose weight. Any activity burns calories, cardiovascular-style workouts can burn more calories than weight-based workouts. But there are benefits from lifting weights to help weight loss too (metabolism boost).

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: Yes you can, but you'll be doing the same stuff over and over, which your body will get used to.

The basics are that it's calories in vs calories out when it comes to weight loss, so doing what you're saying will work to lose weight (if your diet is good). Your body will get used to the movement that you're doing though, so the results might decrease after a long period of doing the same thing a few times a week.

To lose weight it might also be a good idea to start swimming, it's great because it won't put a lot of strain on your joints which can be a problem for overweight people.